# Variable Range VBA Using Months

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a variable range that will update and bring in a different range of values based on what month it is.

```
January C8:D8
February C9:D9
March C10:D10
April C11:D11
May C12:D12
June C13:D13
July C14:D14
August C15:D15
September C16:D16
October C17:D17
November C18:D18
December C19:D19
```

These are the ranges I need based on what month it is.

My Existing Code:

```
Sub PullDataFromClosedWorkbook()

Dim Source As Workbook

Set Source = Workbooks.Open("H:\Integration Projects\Chk Req & Customer 
Payment Sheet\Chk Reqs\Check Request.xlsm", True, True)
'bring to this workbook

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C2").Formula = Source.Worksheets("Consolidated 
Summary").Range("C11:D11").Copy

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Source.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

My first idea was to create an if function that based on a drop down list with the months in it, that it could vlookup the month and set the range to that. Not sure how to do this in vba.

Comment: Use the [Month Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/month-function) to get the month number, and then `Offset` from the Range "C7:D7".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the [Month Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/month-function) to return the current month number, which you can then use as an `Offset` from a starting range.

For example, since it's August, `Month(Date)` returns 8. If your starting range is `C7:D7`, `Range("C7:D7").Offset(Month(Date))` refers to `C15:D15`.

So your code might look something like this (UNTESTED).

```
Sub PullDataFromClosedWorkbook()
    Dim Source As Workbook

    Set Source = Workbooks.Open("H:\Integration Projects\Chk Req & Customer Payment Sheet\Chk Reqs\Check Request.xlsm", True, True)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C2").Value = Source.Worksheets("Consolidated Summary").Range("C7:D7").Offset(Month(Date)).Value
    Source.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I had a +1 to my month formula since we bill a month ahead. Would you have any insight on how I could do this for multiple woorkbooks in a folder with the same fixed range and tab?

Comment: +1 will not work if the current month is December - you'll want to `Offset` 1 row in that case, but as is the code will `Offset` 13. So you'll need to handle that possibility. If the answer is acceptable, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark beside it, and then ask a new question as needed - although SO has examples of how to do what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, I put in an if stmt saying:
    If MyMonth > "12" Then MyMonth = Month(MyDate) - 12